# How to install new skin(Theme) in DNN 8 and activate it? I have tried this but it install the skin but not activate

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-5

How to install new skin(Theme) in DNN 8 and activate it? I have tried this and it install the skin but not activate. While trying to active/update from one to other skin page was reloaded but no action performs. Previous skin only shown and applies.

Can anyone tell me the issue for this? Can anyone provide the steps to apply the skin on particular site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Skin via the Host/Extensions page
2. Navigate to the Admin/Site Settings page, choose the Skin and Containers there. This will set the default SKIN for any page that doesn't have a page level skin.
3. To change Page Level skins, go to the Page Settings for a page, change the skin there.

Comment: I am applying same this steps but still its not working.

Comment: Any errors thrown on the page? Any errors thrown in the Admin/Event Viewer page?

Comment: No error no notification or warning only reload the page